# Task Category for custom ETW events showing as number instead of name in Event Viewer

Tags: etw

I am implementing logging in our application using ETW.

- I used ecmangen.exe to create the manifest with a set of custom events, templates, tasks and keywords.
- I used mc.exe to compile and generated corresponding C# class for use in my code.
- I used this generated class in our code to emit events.
- I imported the manifest via wevtutil and captured events via event trace session (Win2K8R2 - Performance - Data Collector Sets)

When I open the generated trace file via Event Viewer, I see the events I was expecting.  But I found that the custom task categories and keywords are showing in their numeric form, instead of their names.

Should these values be translated?  Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: nevermind...  i realized that i left the description fields blank while constructing my manifest via ecmangen.exe...